# UltraEdit / Unix regular expressions. I want to replace all lines with a name + whitespace + number with a name + # + number SANTIAGO 80,00

Tags: ultraedit

UltraEdit / Unix regular expressions. I want to replace all lines with a name + whitespace + number with a name + # + number

Example : SANTIAGO 80,00 will be replaced with SANTIAGO#80,00 and all the lines will proceed like that

I can find what I want searching in Unix expression :  [^t^b][0-9]

Answer (score 0):

UltraEdit has three regular expression engines.

First solution using **UltraEdit** regular expression engine with a [tagged regular expression](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/tagged-expressions.html):

Find what: `^([^t ]^)^([0-9]^)`
Replace with: `^1#^2`

Second solution using **Unix** or **Perl** regular expression engine doing the same as above also using [marking groups and backreferences](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/perl-regular-expressions-backreferences.html):

Find what: `([\t ])([0-9])`
Replace with: `\1#\2`

These two solutions search for a horizontal tab character or a normal space followed by a digit, tag those two characters for back-referencing them in replace string which inserts `#` between them.

With the most powerful **Perl** regular expression it is also possible to just insert `#` between tab/space and a digit which results in less data recorded for undo.

Find what: `(?<=[\t ])(?=\d)`
Replace with: `#`

The **Perl** regular expression search string uses [a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) to find a position on where to insert `#`.

Also possible with **Perl** regular expression engine:

Find what: `[\t ]\K(?=\d)`
Replace with: `#`

This is the same as above, but with simply searching for a tab or space and resetting the start location of $0 to the position after the whitespace character instead of using a positive lookbehind before checking with positive lookahead if next character is a digit.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I really appreciate.